# Add custom metadata tag to a video in android

Tags: android, kotlin, video, metadata

I have an Android project which I cloned from https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-Camera

The project works fine and captures both images and video.

I want to edit the metadata of the output file to include a custom tag like "comment": "This is a simple comment"

I have tried using mp4parser, but no documentation that explain how to add/change metadata.

If anyone has managed to do please share how to.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try searching on "EXIF data"

Comment: I have tried this but works only with images

Comment: @RichardKamere _"...How to add/change metadata"_ the answer is different depending on the format (or file type) of your input _"video"_. MP4Parser is for files that end with `.mp4` (so you cannot use it for `.webm` or `.mkv` or `.avi` etc if that is what you are calling _"videos"_ in this question). Confirm to us if your files are MP4 or something else?